# Flatten UIViews Subviews to UIImage iPhone 3.0

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cgcontext

I have a UIView that has several UIImageViews as subviews.  Each of these subviews has had different affine transform applied.  I would like to take what amounts to a screen capture of my UIView, capturing it as a UIImage, or some other image representation.

The method I have tried already, rendering the layers to a CGContext with:

```
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

doesn't preserve the positioning or other affine transformations of my subviews.

I would really appreciate a kick in the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: You go it.  I just had to change self.view.size to self.view.frame.size  and use renderInContext.

I'm not sure how I missed this, I guess the key phrase from Apple's docs is "Renders in the coordinate space of the layer."

Thanks!

Comment: Beginning with iOS4, you should use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0)

Comment: Use `YES` instead if you want it to be opaque. Helps performance if you don't need alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift 2.x version:

```
// This flattens <allViews> into single UIImage
func flattenViews(allViews: [UIView]) -> UIImage? {
    // Return nil if <allViews> empty
    if (allViews.isEmpty) {
        return nil
    }

    // If here, compose image out of views in <allViews>
    // Create graphics context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, CGInterpolationQuality.High)

    // Draw each view into context
    for curView in allViews {
        curView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(curView.frame, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    }

    // Extract image & end context
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Return image
    return image
}
```